# Escaping automatic encoding of & character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, escaping

I want to create a form button whose input value is a font icon. FontAwesome in this case. So I use a entity such as this for the input value: `&#xf043;` In plain HTML styled in CSS with `font-family: FontAwesome`, everything works as expected:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn fa-input" value="&#xf043; Input">
```

However, I want to create this element using JavaScript. In that case the & character seems always to end up being encoded so my entity comes out as &#xf107; Needles to say, that prints out literally instead of the font icon. How do manage to not have that & character encoded?

Below is the Javascript I am using

```
var button = utility.dom.createElement('input', {
  'type': 'button', 
  'className': 'fonticon', 
  'value': '&#xf107;',
  'title': 'bla bla bla',
  'tabIndex': 1000
});
```

and the CSS

```
.fonticon {
  font-family:FontAwesome;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the value using JavaScript instead of hardcoding it into your HTML, use a JavaScript escape sequence instead, such as `\uF107`. Your code for the button's value should change to:

```
'value': '\uf107',
```

By the way, U+F107 doesn't appear to be a valid character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f107/index.htm

Comment: F107 is a FontAwesome icon character. Mentioned that is the question :)